# Transactions with Spring Cache Abstraction and JDBC DAO

Tags: java, spring, caching, transactions, locking

I'm testing out Spring's `@Cacheable` features with EHCache but I can't find anything on whether this works with Spring's `@Transactional` annotations.

I am placing `@Cacheable` and `@CacheEvict` on DAO methods while `@Transactional` are on service methods.

Suppose my User DAO looks like this:

```
@Cacheable(value="users", key="#id")
User find(BigInteger id);

@CacheEvict(value="users", key="#user.id")
void update(User user);

@CacheEvict(value="users", key="#id")
void delete(BigInteger id);
```

A problem may arise when, for example, getUser() is called while removeFriend() is in progress, because the user with the stale friend count would be re-cached (or would it?):

```
public User getUser(userId) {
    return userDao.find(userId);
}

@Transactional
public void removeFriend(userId, friendId) {
    friendDao.remove(friendId);
    user.setFriendCount(--numFriends);
    userDao.update(user);
    // do some other stuff
}
```

How can I ensure that this doesn't update the cache before the database transaction has completed? Do I place `@CacheEvict` on service methods in addition to the DAO methods? Or, do I add read/write locking to the service methods? And if so to locking, are there any libraries to lock based on id since I would only want to lock on each user instead of locking globally, e.g. `@GuardedBy("userLocks.getReadLock(#userId)")`? Is there a generally accepted way of handling caching and transactions?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I should've looked into EHCache documentation a bit more because the answer is [here](http://www.ehcache.org/generated/2.10.0/html/ehc-all/#page/Ehcache_Documentation_Set%2Fco-tx_configuring_transactional_cache.html%23).

EHCache 2.4+ works with Spring's @Transactional annotation. Just need to configure a transaction manager lookup.

Comment: This documentation is likely also relevant:
http://ehcache.org/documentation/integrations/spring

Answer (score 1):

The docs make no mention of the caching abstraction having any interactions with other annotation driven Spring features.

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html

The caching abstraction is pretty new and seems fairly small in scope at the moment.

Most likely you'll need to rearchitect your code to use the caching in a way that lines up better with your order of operations.

Comment: Thanks sdouglass. I guess I won't be able to use the spring caching abstraction. I think it's a pretty big feature gap, since caching is often used on top of database calls. Transactions are mentioned in the documentation ("Similar to the transaction support, ..."), but unfortunately in the wrong context!

Comment: It would be great if they could provide some integration. I wonder though if what you're hitting isn't just a basic concurrency issue? You could always resort to synchronization/semaphores/etc. if you really want to enforce "don't allow any threat to call method X while any other thread is in method Y".

Comment: Without caching, [at]Transactional provides all the synchronization we need; with caching, it becomes more complex - as you said, we may need to add synchronization. However, synchronization at the service method level will not work well with [at]Transactional because transactions wrap around the method. It seems that to add caching (in the way we require), we cannot use [at]Transactional or [at]Cacheable.